# Registration process in Salesforce sites

Tags: force.com-sites

I want to implement a registration process in salesforce site where a person can go and register himself. After then when he login, his uid & password will get authenticated and allow him to enter.

Can anyone help me how to take a approach to this solution.

What i thought.

1. I will have a custom object. When the user will register, his uid & password will get stored in fields of the object.
2. When he login, his uid & password will be queried and if match is successful he will able to login.

Please let me know if there is any other approach.

Regards

Comment: You are talking about [Site.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Site.com) not [Force.com Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites) right?

Comment: force.com sites..

Answer (score 1):

Use login settings if you want to let users register for and log in to your portal from your public Force.com site. For example, users browsing through an ideas site can register and login directly from that site, and as authenticated users, they can then vote, add comments, and participate in the ideas community. When users successfully log in, they leave the public site and enter the associated portal seamlessly.
Note
Only Customer Portals can be used for self-registration. Partner portals do not support self-registration.
The Authenticated Website high-volume portal user license is specifically designed to be used with Force.com sites. Because it's designed for high volumes, it should be a cost-effective option to use with Force.com sites.

Everything you need resides here :

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.pdf﻿

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_login_and_registration_settings.htm&language=en

Answer (score 0):

When you add a Force.com Site to an org a set of pages and classes are automatically added that include [self-registration, login and change password pages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_login_and_registration_settings.htm&language=en). These make use of the [Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm) class that hooks into the platform's standard authentication mechanisms. You can modify these pages to match the styling of the rest of your Force.com Site pages.

There is no need to build your own version of this.

Comment: So this means that if i create a custom vf page where user can register and then login, is not going to work..

Comment: @Sid You can build your own page and hook it to the underlying Site class. But if you don't want to use that Site class either then you would also have to build your own session and access control mechanism. Also security is not easy to get right - for example you should never store a password directly - and so creating your own adds risk.